# How to delete association with parent controller update action? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm using Rails 4

I need to delete association `Box` with `link_to` method. The problem is that I have to do it from parrent controller and `method: patch`. my corrent code is doing nothing because I don't know how to use `data:` for link_to.

```
#views/modifications/show.html.erb
<% @modification.boxes.each do |box| %> 
  <tr>
    <td><%= box.name %></td> 
    <td><%= link_to "delete", @modification, remote: true, method: :patch %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

By the way, this is used with Ajax so page doesn't need to be reloaded.

Comment: The HTTP methods PATCH can be used to update partial resources. curious to know why you use patch for delete

Comment: When I use `<%= link_to "delete", box, remote: true, method: :delete %>` ajax can't refresh partial from modifications views, because its on boxes_controller and not modifications_controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to do it

You don't *have* to do anything in *any* way - if Microsoft can release Windows for all the PC's in the world, I'm sure you can get this working.

---

You have several issues, the most important of which being... **how do you identify the `box` object to delete?**

The whole point of [`nested resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) (which is what you need) is to give you the ability to identify a "parent" object *and* a child object.

Your current setup prevents you from identifying the `box` you wish to remove. Ideally, you should use the following code to get it sorted:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :modifications do
   resources :boxes, only: :destroy
end

#app/views/modifications/show.html.erb
<% @modification.boxes.each do |box| %> 
  <tr>
    <td><%= box.name %></td> 
    <td><%= link_to "delete", [@modification, box], remote: true, method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/boxes_controller.rb
class BoxesController < ApplicationController
   def destroy
      @modification = Modification.find params[:modification_id]
      @box          = @modification.boxes.find params[:id]
      @box.destroy
   end
end
```

Comment: Wow! what just happened? my ajax is working perfect now. when I before used this `<%= link_to "delete", box, remote: true, method: :delete %>` it couldn't refresh partial boxes_list.

Comment: I just write your code and now jquery can render 'modifications/boxes_list'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to using `link_to` with delete method on box destroy path, like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', box_path(box), method: :delete, remote: true %>
```